# ActiveRecord find record by HABTM references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have simple book-author HABTM model:

books -> books_authors -> authors

I have an array of author ids + title string and need to find if there is already a book with that title and having exactly those given authors.

Any ideas ho to do that using ActiveRecord in Rails 3?

Answer (score 2):

The best practice for implementing habtm is now has_many :though

```
models/Book.rb
class Book <  < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :authors
has_many :authorships, :through => author

models/Authorship.rb
class Authorship < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :book
belongs_to :author

models/Author.rb
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base 
has_many :authorships
has_many :authors, :through => :authorships
```

Comment: There's no problem to make HABTM, but still how can I find a book by its title AND a number of given Author ids?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (**untested!**):

```
books.
  joins('inner join books_authors on books.id = book_id').
  where(:title => 'search_title').
  where('author_id in (?)', author_ids.join(',')).
  group('id').
  having('count(*) = ?', author_ids.size)
```

The idea is to filter by the authors you are searching for, and then compare the count of authors found per book with the count of authors you are searching for.

Comment: i've come to another solution (see below) while trying to understand yours :) thansk a lot

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found so far is this:

```
Book.find(:all, :joins => :authors,
                :conditions =>
                            ["books.title = ? AND authors_books.author_id IN (?)",
                             book_title,
                             [1,2,3])
```

But unfortunately you have to iterate then to remove books with fewer authors (1, or 1+2 etc.)

Now i need to figure out a way to replace SQL `IN` statement with some sort of  "_is_exactly_this_collection_" operation... Any ideas?